# How do I parse by regular expressions only on filtered lines on Cloudwatch log insights?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Is there a way to restructure this cloudwatch insights query so that it runs faster?

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /NewProductRequest/
| parse @message /.*"productType":\s*"(?<productType>\w+)"/
| stats count(*) group productType
```

I am running it over a limited period (1 day's worth of logs). It is taking very long to run.

When I remove the `parse` command, and `count(*)` the filtered lines: there are only 2500 matches out of 20,000,000 lines: the query returns in several seconds

With the `parse` command, the query takes >15 minutes. I can see the throughput drop from ~1GBps to ~2MBps.

Running a `parse` regexp on 2500 filtered lines should be negligible. It takes less then 2 seconds if I download the filtered results to my macbook and run the regexp in Python.

This leads me to believe that cloudwatch is running the `parse` command on every line in the log, and not just the filtered lines.

Is there a way to **restructure** my query so that the `parse` command will run after my filter command? ( Effectively parsing 2.5k lines instead of 20 million lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the `.*` at the beginning of the expression increases performance. If you only searching for a string starting after **any** character sequence (`.*`), then this solution will work for you. This does not solve problems if the beginning of your regexp is anything other than `.*`